# Run mysqld with root privileges

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mysql

I wanted to run `mysqld` as the root user.

I'm running Ubuntu 21.04 and have installed `mysql-server`.

MySQL version:

```
mysql  Ver 8.0.25-0ubuntu0.21.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
```

*Changing the file ownership to root*

```
chown -R root /var/lib/mysql
```

*/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf*

```
[mysqld]
user        = root
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket  = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
```

When I start the MySQL service via:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

I am getting an error:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2021-05-25 08:29:56 PDT; 23s ago
    Process: 2413 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Process: 2421 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 2421 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Server startup in progress"
      Error: 13 (Permission denied)
```

However, if I change the file permissions of */var/lib/mysql* back to the *mysql* user, the service starts.

Please let me know the solution for how I can run this as root.

If I am doing anything wrong please suggest clear steps.

Ref:
[1]: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/changing-mysql-user.html

Comment: Why are you trying to run MySQL as root? This seems unnecessary 

Comment: Just a small note: when my MySQL is run as root it is possible for privilege escalation. So in trying to understand and replicate this for demonstration. Ref: https://redteamnation.com/mysql-user-defined-functions/

Comment: This looks like an ACL issue (apparmor/selinux).  Does anything show up in the system logs?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the link you provided

> On Linux, for installations performed using a MySQL repository or RPM packages, the MySQL server mysqld should be started by the local mysql operating system user. **Starting by another operating system user is not supported by the init scripts that are included as part of the MySQL repositories.**
>
> On Unix (or Linux for installations performed using tar.gz packages) , the MySQL server mysqld can be started and run by any user.

So in order to run `mysqld` as root you need to install it from the tar.gz package. Then the steps you've already tried should be sufficient.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/binary-installation.html has instructions for how to install mysql, and https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/ has the download links.

I should note that it is generally *not* a good idea to run `mysqld` as root. It sounds like you're aware of that, and are trying to explore the exploits that might be possible from that, but other viewers may not be as security-conscious.

Answer (score 0):

**Normally it is not recommended to run mysql as root** !!

However this is your call, your error is `Permission denied`, which means you're attempting to start the process as user/group mysql. Since you're using systemd to start the mysql service, please check the systemd service configuration:

/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service

Change the User and Group to root:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
User=mysql
Group=mysql
```

Do not forget to reload the systemd demon after changes:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```